# Have button with custom image and link

Tags: html, button

I've already looked around the internet, but none of those answers have helped me in any way. I'm a beginner and was wondering how I could make a button (that looks like the facebook logo)  link to my facebook page once clicked? I've used the code below to no avail.

```
 <input type="button" src="images/facebook.png" 
width="175" height="60" >
</section>
</header>
```

[image: This is what it keeps showing me and I have no idea why]

This is what it keeps showing me and I have no idea why

Comment: Why do you want a button?  Why not just a link?  And, you need `type="image"` if you want an image there.  Or, you could use the HTML5 `<button>`.

Comment: Gave you a reply below but Brad is correct also. I would however suggest using a sprite so you can show states. It's prob. what you want anyway. the code below should point u appropriately.

Comment: @Brad it's for aesthetic reasons. I know how to make a hyperlink, but doing this seemed like a cool idea

Comment: @ThatGuyThere, You can style a link however you want.  Use an anchor tag.  Crawlers, screen readers, and console browsers will appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

an alternative to this can be, you could add link to image.

```
<a href="http://example.com"><img src="images/facebook.png" /></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Style the button with a css background image.

```
<input type="button" class="myclass" />

/*css*/
input.myclass { 
background-image: url('image.png'); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;  
background-position: 0px 0px; }
```

If you want to get a little nicer create this background image as a sprite. so you'd have the height of the button and then on hover change the background position so as to show a hover state.

```
/*hover css*/
input.myclass:hover { background-position: 0px -25px; } 
/* where 25 is height of your btn */
```